# Proving an identity of the Pettis integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological vector spaces such that $X^{\ast}$ and $Y^{\ast}$ respectively separate points on the aforementioned spaces. Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $Q$, a compact Hausdorff space and let $T\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ and $f:Q\to X$ be continuous. I want to prove that
$$T\int_{Q} f d\mu=\int_{Q}(Tf)d\mu.$$

I said: let $y:=\int_{Q}fd\mu$ whose uniqueness follows from the fact that $X^{\ast}$ separates points on $X$. Moreover, if $\Lambda\in Y^{\ast}$, then $\Lambda T\in X^{\ast}$. Then, from the definition of the Pettis integral, we get:
$$(\Lambda T)(y)=(\Lambda T)\left(\int_{Q}f d\mu\right)=\int_{Q}(\Lambda T)(f)d\mu,$$
for every $\Lambda\in Y^{\ast}$. Thus
$$T\int_{Q}fd\mu=\int_{Q}(Tf)d\mu.$$
However, I am unsure about the final step. Furthermore, we have not established uniqueness of $y$. Certainly, this holds if $X$ is a Fréchet space, or if we were working on a Banach algebra.

**Edit:** Please feel free to comment that the existence of $y$ cannot be proven under the current assumptions placed on $f$.

Comment: Is the existence of $\int_Q f\,d\mu$ part of your hypothesis, or do you want to conclude it from the assumptions on $Q,\mu$, and $f$?

Comment: @DanielFischer The latter. I wonder if I can conclude the existence from the assumptions I have already made. I would assume that if the existence of $\int_{Q}f d\mu$ was part of my hypothesis then I would already be done?

Comment: I'm sceptical about that. If $X$ isn't complete, it could be that the integral would lie outside $X$. I don't know for sure, though. And if $X$ isn't locally convex, that might pose another problem. If $\int_Q f\,d\mu$ exists, then $\int_Q Tf\,d\mu$ exists too, and $\int_Q Tf\,d\mu = T\int_Q f\,d\mu$. That part is harmless.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am also skeptical and think that the question is most probably ill posed. I think the only way to remedy it would be to make the assumption that $f$ is a continuous $\mathcal{B}(X)$ valued function on $Q$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're aiming at. The only problem we have is the existence of $\int_Q f\,d\mu$. (Aside, I just noticed that you only assume $\mu$ to be a Borel measure. If we don't make a finiteness assumption on $\mu$, examples where the integral doesn't exist are easy to come by.) Changing the codomain of $f$ to another space won't help, unless we impose niceness conditions. But we could impose those also on $X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I quote from Walter's Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, p. 259: "If $A$ is a Banach algebra, $f$ is a continuous $A$-valued function on some compact Hausdorff space $Q$ on which a complex Borel measure $\mu$ is defined, then $\int f\,d\mu$ exists". Now, $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is indeed a Banach algebra which, based on the aforementioned quote, would establish the existence of $\int f\,d\mu$.

Comment: $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is only a Banach-algebra if $X$ is a Banach space. In that case, we have no problem with the existence. (At least for regular Borel measures, I think. Then the Bochner integral of $f$ over $Q$ exists, and that would agree with the Pettis integral, unless something very weird happens.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, you are correct. I seem to have overlooked the fact that $X$ is only a topological vector space. Then I am at a loss!

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't see your comment regarding the Bochner integral of $f$. Checking the definition, it seems that $f:X\to Q$ is Bocher integrable iff $\int_{X}\|f\|_{Q}d\mu<\infty$. But what is $\|\cdot\|_{Q}$ here?

Comment: Okay, Rudin proves the existence of the integral under the assumptions that $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure, $Q$ compact, $f$ continuous, and $\overline{co}(f(Q))$ compact. The normalisation to a probability measure is clearly unnecessary (it simplifies some proofs), it suffices that the total variation of $\mu$ is finite (and if that isn't the case, it's easy to find continuous $f$ such that the integral doesn't exist). That leaves the question of the closed convex hull of $f(Q)$. I don't think that's a necessary condition, but some niceness will be required.

Comment: That's not what I know as the [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral). (Note that the measure space is called $X$ [corresponds to our $Q$] and the Banach space is called $B$ [corresponds to our $X$] there.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Since $Q$ is compact then $f(Q)$ is also compact. However, Rudin only seems to hint that the closed convex hull of $f(Q)$ is compact when $X$ is a Fréchet space.

Comment: Well, there's the condition of Bochner-measurability. But the main thing is that you mixed up the spaces. We'd look at $\int_Q \lVert f\rVert_X\,d\mu$ here. And coming to think of it, a Bochner-measurable function must have essentially separable range, and that places restrictions on $Q$ (or stronger conditions than just continuity on $f$). Anyway, $X$ being a Fréchet space is a sufficient condition for the closed convex hull of $f(Q)$ to be compact. I don't think it's necessary. But more, the compactness of the closed convex hull of $f(Q)$ is a sufficient condition for the integral to exist,

Comment: but I think it's not a necessary condition. However, a necessary and sufficient condition is unlikely to be easy to state, unless it's tautological.